# URLs: enable space to indicate possible breakpoints?

Tags: hyperref, urls

With `url.sty`, I would like to use spaces in URLs to indicate possible points for linebreak but without the spaces actually being displayed in the output. This idea is actually inspired by this little passage from the `url.sty` package documentation:

> Note that it seems logical to allow the sole option “[spaces]” to let
>   input spaces indicate break points, but not to display them in the
>   output. This would be easy to implement, but is left out to avoid(?)
>   confusion.

Well, so *how* would I implement it? :)

(Note that the questionmark was in the original ...)

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}
So, here we go: 
\url{http://www.this-is-a-long.com/long long long long long long
long/domain/name?with=a &lot=variables &that=I &would=like &to=be &able=to
&break=at &space=characters}
\end{document}
```

**Edit 1:**

What I do *not* want is the spaces really to appear in the displayed URL. This is why the `obeyspaces` package option of `url.sty` cannot be used. What I mean is to use spaces in the source code only to indicate possible break points without them appearing in the output.

Activating spaces as breakpoints is precisely the purpose of the `spaces` option. So it would be natural to use

```
\usepackage[spaces]{url}
```

to achieve the functionality I want: spaces as breakpoints but not being displayed in the output. However, as the documentation, page 2, states the `spaces` option can only be used in combination with `obeyspaces` but not stand alone which would be the logical configuration for the functionality I want. Please see the above quotation from the manual, which suggests that not using `obeyspaces` but using `spaces` is deliberately deactivated to "avoid" confusion athough it would be easy to implement.

So my question is: How can it "easily" be implemented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This combination seems to work. The `obeyspaces` options activates the handling of spaces, the redefinition than gives it the wanted output/action. The `spaces` option gives `\Url@sppen` a "breakable" value, but is not really needed. E.g. `\def\Url@space{\penalty\UrlBreakPenalty}` would work too.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[obeyspaces,spaces]{url}

\textwidth1cm
\makeatletter
\def\Url@space{\penalty\Url@sppen}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
So, here we go:


\url{http://www.this-is-a-long.com/long long long long long long
long/domain/name?with=a &lot=variables &that=I &would=like &to=be &able=to
&break=at &space=characters}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No sorry, it does not produce the desired result as the `obeyspaces` option makes all the spaces appear in the URL. This is why I asked the question: The idea is about using spaces in the URL only to indicate possible break points but without them actually being displayed in the output. Please refer to the `url` package manual page 2.

Comment: I edited my original question above to make my point more clearer.

Comment: In my screenshot there are no spaces in the output (e.g. `long long` prints as `longlong`). So where is your problem?

Comment: OK I'm sorry that's right!! Don't know what I did wrong when I was first testing your solution. I cannot upvote the solution because my voting is 'locked' ...

Comment: I edited the answer, this should unlock it.

Answer (score 3):

A bit stricter than what Ulrike Fischer did:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[obeyspaces]{url}


\makeatletter
\def\Url@space{\penalty10}
\def\UrlBreakPenalty{100000}
\def\UrlBigBreakPenalty{100000}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
So, here we go: 
\url{http://www.this-is-a-long.com/long long long long long long
long/domain/name?with=a &lot=variables &that=I &would=like &to=be &able=to
&break=at &space=characters}
\end{document}
```

This should allow breaks only at spaces (perhaps I forgot one or two penalties).

I did not use the `spaces` option, because I set the penalties to absolute values and did not use any `url`-internal variables like `\Url@sppen` which is set to `\UrlBreakPenalty` when you use `spaces`. Therefore the `spaces` option wouldn't change anything in my answer.

Comment: You may want to provide a quick discussion of why you're not including the `spaces` option.

Comment: @Mico The answer to that is, because I set the penalties to numbers and did not use internal variables like `\Url@sppen` which is set to `\UrlBreakPenalty` if you call the `spaces` option. So the `spaces` option changes the behavior in Ulrike Fischers answer but not in mine.